# Graph API FB v2 change "/me/friends" & "friends_events" permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I built a web app, via GRAPH API V1, enabling user to get access to :

- his friends events (attending & Maybe)
- some informations regarding each one of these events

It worked well.

But, as you may guess, since the migration to Graph API v2, the query "/me/friends" does not allow me to provide this service. (returning only the list of friends using my web app)

Do you think there is a way to bypass this restriction and access to user's friend's events? via an other API query or something else?

Comment: No there is no way to bypass the restriction. If there was it would be a bug and it would be fixed

Comment: So it's a major revolution in the Graph API history, isn't it ? 
I'm surprised not having heard more people complaining about it on the web.

Comment: Yes it is a major change. That is why it was announced during F8 in April. And why there are messages all over developers.facebook.com that tell you to upgrade

Comment: Ok thank you. Last question : Since the release of Graph API v2, according to you, What is the best way to source Facebook events - Ultimately your friends' events - but as I understand you cannot do it anymore, events of your city for example ? (scrapping could be a solution) Thanks again

Comment: Scraping is not a solution. That is not allowed if you don't have written permission from Facebook

Comment: I still can't believe such a downgrade.. Thanks.

Comment: It is an upgrade for users